# Google Vision Api in python stopped working - beginner coder alarm

Tags: python, vision-api

I was interested in coding a long time. So this year I got a job where I was supposed to scrape text from old event programs. The pictures where terrible quality and results with normal OCR where horrible. I checked the google vision api and tested it manually and the results where great, so I used this opportunity to learn about coding.( I did some python before but the lack of usefulness always drove me away).

I wrote this program, I know its walking on crouches but it worked and did exactly what I wanted for 3 months now. I dont use it regularly but today when I wanted to use it again, it didnt work any more it just jumps to the end of the program, and finishes without making the api requests, at least so it seems to me.

I am really mostly finished with my work and this request doesnt make sense in terms of efficiency but I am just curious why the program I created suddenly stopped working.

If somebody can hint me in the right direction I would highly appreciate it, also if somebody wants to use the program, if it works for them sure let it work instead of yourself :D

I am not sure but I am using linux mint and maybe it stopped working because of some updates of python or vision-api or something.

```
# coding=utf-8

from google.cloud import vision
import os
import io
import sys



reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

directory = "/home/weareone/Documents/programming/test/here"

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/home/weareone/Documents/programming/test/key.json"

def workinghard(page):

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    #file_name = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(__file__), page) # Loads the image into memory

    #page_er = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(page))) <--- my improvisation

    with io.open( page, 'rb') as image_file: # after io.open.(file_name <---exchanged with "page")

        content = image_file.read()

    request = {
        "image": {
            "content": content

        
    },

        "features": [
            {
            "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
            }
        
        ]
    }

    response = client.annotate_image(request)



    storage = response.full_text_annotation.text


    return storage



def listdirs(folder):
    return [
        d for d in (os.path.join(folder, d1) for d1 in os.listdir(folder))
        if os.path.isdir(d)
    ]



directories = listdirs(directory)

for year in directories:

    logtxt = open(year + ".txt", "w+" )


    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(year):

        files.sort()
        
        for file23 in files:



            if file23.endswith('.jpg'):

                pathparent = os.path.join(year,file23)

                logtxt.write(workinghard(pathparent))
                
                logtxt.write("-------------------------------------------------------------------------")

                print(pathparent)

            


    logtxt.close()


print("DONE")
```

Thank you very much dear internet

EDIT: I solved it by changing this line the statement apaprently equaled to FALSE.
`if file23.endswith('.JPG'):`

Comment: If your program jumps immediately to the end then it is likely that you main `for` loop is doing nothing. The most likely cause of that is that `listdirs()` is not returning what you expect. Print out the value it returns and examine what you get carefully.

Comment: So I checked I didnt describe the problem good so the .txt files I am creating are created but nothing ever gets appended. I now printed the directories and it creates totally what I expected: the file paths.  I then printed out the files23 and it does what i expected it to do.    But I found when I printed something in the `if file23.endswith('.jpg'):` statement and it didnt execute. So I assumed it must equal to false and I tried to change it to ´if file23.endswith('.JPG'):´ and it worked instantly.

Comment: And again it was a conflict between man and machine and the first having a different expectation of what is possible than the second. I am curious what could cause such an behaviour probably my very basic coding and not sticking to guidelines. :) Anyway thanks for your tip it made me progress my adventure and helped expanding my horizon.